# Python ValueError: substring not found - Error defining a word

Tags: python, error-handling, substring, error-code

I'm trying to make a program that when you type a sentence it asks for a word to search and it will tell you where in the sentence it sentence occurs 
the code is as follows:

```
loop=1
while loop:
    sent = str(input("Please type a sentence without punctuation:"))
    lows = sent.lower()
    word = str(input("please enter a word you would want me to locate:"))
    if word:
        pos = sent.index(word)
        pos = pos + 1
        print(word, "appears at the number:",pos,"in the sentence.")
    else:
        print ("this word isnt in the sentence, try again")
        loop + 1
        loop = int(input("Do you want to end ? (yes = 0); no = 1):"))
```

It seems to work fine until I type it incorrectly eg hello my name is Will
and the word I want to find is it instead of "sorry this doesn't occur in the sentence" but infact ValueError : substring not found

I honestly dont know how to fix this and need help please.

Comment: wrap your index call in a `try/except ValueError` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what happens for `str.index` and `str.find` when substring is not found.

```
>>> help(str.find)
Help on method_descriptor:

find(...)
    S.find(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

    Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
    such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
    arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

    Return -1 on failure.

>>> help(str.index)
Help on method_descriptor:

index(...)
    S.index(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

    Like S.find() but raise ValueError when the substring is not found.
```

For `str.index` you will need a `try/except` statement to handle invalid input. For `str.find` an if statement checking if the return value isn't `-1` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

A little different from your approach.

```
def findword():
    my_string = input("Enter string: ")
    my_list = my_string.split(' ')
    my_word = input("Enter search word: ")
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if my_word in my_list[i]:
            print(my_word," found at index ", i)
            break
    else:
        print("word not found")

def main():
    while 1:
        findword()
        will_continue = int(input("continue yes = 0, no = 1; your value => "))
        if(will_continue == 0):
            findword()
        else:
            print("goodbye")
            break;
main()
```

Comment: this was easy to understand.